# How to stop kitten leaving toys in the litter box?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, toys

I have just purchased a Turkish Van kitten from a breeder. He is about 4 months old, and I have only had him for a little over a week. There are 2 issues that I am dealing with about this sweet little boy. He is very shy and timid and hides and every time I enter a room, and he looks like he wants to run, but when I say his name then he is fine. He is afraid of my husband and won't let him touch or go near him. Also, if you make a sudden move or a noise, he runs but will come back by me.

Now for the second question: he will play with a toy and then he will pick it up and carry it to the litter box. That is gross and I don't want him to get discouraged and then think that he shouldn't use the litterbox. What can I do to stop him from doing this yucky habit?

Comment: Is your litter box covered? Or open top?

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason he's doing this is that he's new to your home, and the litter box is the one place that he's sure is ***his***. So naturally he wants to keep his toy there.

The problem should go away as he settles in. Make sure he has lots of cozy places of his own, where he feels safe. Cat beds, cardboard boxes, cat trees, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I have done this with him and he seems to be doing better with his toys. He is still scared but is getting a little more confident too!